# Visual Studio 2012 Premium unit testing disables internet browsing

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I've just started using unit testing for Visual Studio 2012. For some reason, after performing the unit tests, none of my browsers will "work". IE, Chrome both will act as if my connection is down. To restore it, I have to reset my Internet Explorer settings. And it is other people on our team that is having the same issue.

It seems to happen when debugging a test and stopping the execution before it would normally finish.

Has anyone seen this or does anyone have any advice as to what to check that is preventing the traffic?

Comment: Does it entirely disable Internet access, or only for web browsers?

Comment: From what I can tell, it disables browsers. I can ping internet sites from a command prompt. I don't think it disrupts Exchange or Lync access. Good question; I updated my subject.

Comment: I wonder if it messed up the Internet Proxy settings.

Comment: Also, does it do this with _all_ unit tests? If you only have a "Hello, Testing" test, does it disable the browsers?

Comment: Yes. I added a test method that simply did a console.WriteLine(). I set a breakpoint at the writeline and stopped the test. That killed the browsers' ability. So, it seems if I stop the test at the breakpoint: bad. If I allow it to finish execution: good.

Comment: Try the same, but with the dummy test method as the only test in the test project.

Comment: Tried the test in its own test project. Results are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio Update 2 fixes this bug for me.

UPDATE:
Still happens actually, but if I go to Control Panel => Network and Sharing Center
Then Connections Tab
Select my Network Settings and click LAN Settings

Turn off the "Use a proxy server for your LAN".

Everything returns back to normal.